# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'unicode' and 'unicode'

Tags: python, redirect, unicode, tornado, typeerror

I have this redirect in python:

```
self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/networks/{0}/sensors/{0}#tab3".format(netid&sensid)))
```

The URL generated is correct, for example

```
http://localhost:8000/networks/1234567812345678124/sensors/1234/rights
```

but I have this error from Tornado web server

```
self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/networks/{0}/sensors/{0}#tab3".format(netid&sensid)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'unicode' and 'unicode'
```

I have to pass both netid and sensid to the page... in which way I have to write the redirect????

Thank you very much...

ps. i tried with

```
self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/networks/{0}/sensors/{0}#tab3".format(netid, sensid)))
```

but sensid take the value of netid and I have the URL

```
http://localhost:8000/networks/1234567812345678124/sensors/1234567812345678124/rights
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/networks/{0}/sensor/{1}#tab3".format(netid, sensid)))
```

This will put `netid` at the first position (`{0}`) and `sensid` at the second position (`{1}`).

Comment: @sharkbait: No problem :) You can accept this answer as the correct answer by clicking the check mark on the left.